# How to handle nested default value in multi argument function

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Let's say i have a function that takes two arguments `name` and `options` where options is object and i want to set default values only for some keys. If it would be function of one argument, thanks destructuring one can do thing like this

```
function myFunction({
  name = 'name',
  options: { firstOption = "first", secondOption = "second" } = {},
} = {}) {
  console.log(name);
  console.log(firstOption);
  console.log(secondOption);
}
```

But what if i want `myFunction` to take two params? Approach like below :

```
function myFunction(name, options = {firstOption : 'first', secondOption : 'second' }) {
  console.log(name);
  console.log(options.firstOption);
  console.log(options.secondOption);
}
```

Doest work, i want to `myFunction('name', {firstOption : 'anotherFirstOption '})` wouldn't have default value for `options.secondOptions`. Of course i can achieve what i want modifying function body by `options.secondOption = options.secondOption || 'second'` but im looking for function definition level solution. Is it possible ?

Comment: you can destructure setting defaults where you need `function myFunction(name, {firstOption='first', secondOption})`

Comment: How you want to access lets say `firstOption` in function body?  `function myFunction(name, {firstOption='first', secondOption}){ console.log(firstOption)}` will throw error.

Comment: true, it should read `function myFunction(name, {firstOption='first', secondOption}={}) {console.log(firstOption)}`

Comment: Neither one throws an error, What am i missing here ? And what is the actual problem here ?

Comment: My first comment throws an error if you don't pass the second parameter in the call. My correction will log `firstOption` regardless whether any parameters are passed, or be overwritten by the passed options object.

Comment: Right, Still i don't understand the problem this question is trying to solve

Comment: I'm with you there